# jinja error with multi-line code

Tags: jinja2

I'm trying to write a multiline if statement to set a variable in jinja2. But I keep getting an error

the code:

```
{% set subjectName = subject.name %}
{% if(subjectName == ''):
   subjectName = 'empty'
%}
{% endif %}
```

error:

> jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: expected token 'end of statement block', got 'subjectName'

is multiline code not allowed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after searching a bit, this worked for me:

```
{% set subjectName = subject.name %}
{% if(subjectName == '') %}
{% set subjectName = 'empty' %}
{% endif %}
```